# Is any other open source web server available  other than Apache webserver for web application development?

Tags: python, apache, web-applications, webserver

Apart from Apache web server is there any open source web servers available for web application development?

I am looking for a web server developing python web applications and deploy it and test it.

Answer (score 3):

`Apart from Apache web server is there any open source web servers available for web application development?` are you looking for an `HTTP` server or a web framework, the two are quite different.

HTTP servers simply send/recieve requests among other tasks, yes you can use PHP and other tools most commonly through `CGI` or `FCGI` but fundamentally an `HTTP` server simply accepts HTTP requests, some content maybe dynamic if its coming from an underlying framework.

A web framework is a collection of tools used to generate dynamic content, or web apps, many frameworks come with a built in `http` server so you don't have to configure one on your own, but they aren't as powerful or as robust since the underlying frameworks tends to concentrate on generating the content.

`nginx` is one my favorite `HTTP` servers, among the many out there, since it tends to be one of the easier ones to configure.

As for web frameworks, there are many many out there, in the python comunity (giving the `python` tag) `django` tends to be quite popular since it tends to include virtually all the tools you'd ever need to deploy a web app, which include, url dispatchig, database engine + `ORM` `Object Relational Mapper` and its own `templating` engine to render dynamic `html` in its own limited language, to remove as much as possible the logic from the rendering phase.

Usually `django` apps are deployed behind nginx, to control multiple instances of sites on the server, as well as serving static content, web frameworks are not great at it.

Theres also micro-webframeworks like `bottle` which is basically a single python file, its quite cool, I usually use `sqlalchemy` as the `ORM` when building simple `bottle` apps.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/Main) to deploy my Python applications. It's open source, really fast with static content, and works well for me.

From the website:

> Nginx is a free, open-source, high-performance HTTP server and reverse proxy, as well as an IMAP/POP3 proxy server. Igor Sysoev started development of Nginx in 2002, with the first public release in 2004. Nginx now hosts nearly 12.18% (22.2M) of active sites across all domains. Nginx is known for its high performance, stability, rich feature set, simple configuration, and low resource consumption.

I also know [lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/) and [Cherokee](http://www.cherokee-project.com/) support Python webapps.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply Google "Open Source Web Server" you'll get a lot of results.

- Nginx
- Lighttpd
- Cherokee
- Savant
- Tornado

Nginx is probably the best alternative.